# Integrating gRPC with Keycloak for Flutter App - Feasibility and Implementation

Tags: rust, keycloak, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-web

I am exploring the possibility of integrating gRPC with Keycloak for a Flutter application and have several questions regarding this integration. Firstly, is it feasible to use gRPC with Keycloak? Additionally, can Flutter utilize gRPC with OpenID Connect (OIDC) / JWT for authentication?
I'd also like it to be uniform and use gRPC everywhere, is that possible?

I am planning to structure my application as follows:

[image]

I am particularly interested in understanding the best practices and any potential challenges I might face in this setup. Any insights or advice on how to efficiently implement this architecture would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance !